# How to use step module in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I am using [step](https://github.com/creationix/step) module in node.js to get the serial execution but it is not working as expected.

**Code**

```
   //sample
   var goalSteps = [1:{"goal":"faq","page:"faq"},2:{"goal":"offers","page:"offers"}];
   var goalConversion = [];
   var length = goalSteps.length;
    step(
              function getData() {
                var scope= this;
                for(var i =0; i < length ;i++){
                    var filter = goalSteps[i];
                     //get data from database[mongodb]
                    scope.getData(filter,function(res){
                        console.log("result",res);
                        goalConversion[i] = res;
                         if(length-1  == i){
                            this.call();
                          }
                    });
                }

              },
              function final(err, goal) {
                console.log("step2",goalConversion);
              }
        );
```

**Result**

```
      Step2 []
```

Before executing the **getData** function, **final** function got executed.

**Scenario** - Flow what i am expecting

1. I want to loop through the `goalSteps` and to get the data from mongodb.
2. Pushing the result to `goalConversion` array.
3. After getting all the data based on the `goalSteps`.
4. Console the `goalConversion` in the final function.

Any help will be greatful. Any example of step module with similar scenario also great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use group to run common tasks with dynamic numbers and generates combined result of an individual callback  .

```
var goalSteps = [1:{"goal":"faq","page:"faq"},2:{"goal":"offers","page:"offers"}];

step(
    function(){
        var scope= this;
        var group = this.group();
        for(var i =0; i < length ;i++){

            var filter = goalSteps[i];
            //get data from database[mongodb]
            scope.getData(filter, group()); // group() is how you get Step to merge multiple results into an array

         }
    },
    function final(err, goalConversion) {
            console.log("step2", goalConversion); // goalConversion is an array which contains all results
    }
);
```

Comment: thanks for your help. whether i have to call group() from the getData function. IF you don't mind just explain me

Comment: group() is a callback generator for grouped results. It internally keeps track of the number of callbacks issued and preserves their order then giving the result to the next step after all have finished. If there is an error in any of the parallel actions, it will be passed as the first argument to the next step.